# why is adobe photoshop tcp listening on my computer? cloudfront

Tags: macos, security, adobe-photoshop

I closed photoshop and seems like there are no adobe process running. (macos)

Though if i type in terminal:

```
danass$ lsof -i 4
```

i get among others :

```
Adobe\x20 589 danass    9u  IPv4 0xbba65a93885fce1      0t0  TCP localhost:15292 (LISTEN)
```

if i open the port on browser i get :

```
400 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: bcKKiyZPAc9I-ddUyZHt8JpBtUHFt1W7HZZv7wxIwXyKtJRkoqhllA==
```

why am i running a cloudfront instance? what am i sharing using this service?

Comment: Let's get the full name and location of the process in question. In your example, it had PID 589 (see the second column of lsof output). So you'd do something like this: `ps auxww 589`, and then look at the "Command" column (the last column).

Also note it's only binding to localhost (127.0.0.1, the loopback address), so whatever it is, it's only accepting connections from your own machine, unless there's another line that says `…TCP *:15292 (LISTEN)`.

Comment: danass   560   0.0  0.1  4346840  12184   ??  S     2Aug18   9:21.19 /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Desktop Common/ADS/Adobe Desktop Service.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Desktop Service --onOSstartup=true --showwindow=false --waitForRegistration=true - Thx. How can i edit this ? for example turn onOSstartup=true to false?

Comment: Look in /Library/LaunchAgents and /Library/LaunchDaemons for the plist that starts the job and then use launchctl to disable it.